# Question regarding: Vectorization Math of Backpropagation in a Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, mathematics, matrix

**Formula:**
These are the formula I use for backpropagation from [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/backpropagation/):

[image: Formula backpropagation]

**Question:**
If we consider a Neural Network with the structure ***(3,2)***:
[image: Neural network architecture]
And we would start calculating the derivative (for 1 trainings example), we would have a ***(2,1)*** matrix for the error term.
Since $\hat{y} - y$ is a ***(2,1)*** matrix and $g_0'(a_1^m)$ is also a ***(2,1)*** matrix and we multiplicate them element-wise with each other.

If we know want to proceed and calculate the partial derivative with respect to **w** we would need to multiply $\delta$ which is a ***(2,1)*** matrix with $o_i$ which is ***(3,1)*** a matrix which is not possible.

So what to do? :/